# The tables cell size height and width not working in python docx

Tags: python, ms-word, docx, python-docx

I have a document which has over 100 tables and I want to set the tables cell width to 0.54" and the cell height to 0.56". Although, the code has no problems but still the output doesn't have anything changed.

I tried searching for solutions but really didn't find anything I was not doing. I am sure that the code is working great. Here is the code

```
from docx import Document
from docx.shared import Inches


def resize_tables(document, width, height):
    for table in document.tables:
        for row in table.rows:
            for cell in row.cells:
                cell.width = width
                cell.height = height

# Load the Word document
doc = Document(r'C:\Users\Mosta\Downloads\S.docx')

# Specify the desired width and height for the cells
cell_width = Inches(0.54)
cell_height = Inches(0.56)

# Resize all tables
resize_tables(doc, cell_width, cell_height)

# Save the modified document
doc.save(r'C:\Users\Mosta\Downloads\document5.docx')
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting the `autofit` property in each table to `False`?

You might have to set the height for the row, not per each cell, and apply the proper `WD_ROW_HEIGHT_RULE` per row. Also try setting the width per column intead of per cell.

Alternatively, try setting `width` value in `EMU` rather than `Inches`.

Comment: Thank you very much for your assistance. However I instead of doing all of that I made a code to generate these documents so I edited the code to make it adjust it and save it as pdf since a word document is very hard to deal with in this scenario. But I really appreciate your help.